# Delete form data for subsequent ajax calls

Tags: forms, jquery

I have a link that opens a dialog modal asking for a date. When they click submit, javascript takes the form data, generates an ajax call, and returns the response. This works no problem. However if I immediately click the same link again and submit a new date in the form, I get the results from my first ajax POST.

Essentially, subsequent ajax calls are using the original POST data and nothing new. Code has alerts for troubleshooting. Im assuming im setting some var thats not getting reset, but thought this event handler was canceled with the "off", then re-added immediately after and the vars would be in scope to that function alone.

```
<script>
//Modal submit
$(document).off('click', '#SubmitAllChecks');
$(document).on('click', '#SubmitAllChecks', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#AllChecks');
    var url = form.attr('action');
    var method = form.attr('method');
    var data = form.serializeArray();
    $.each(data, function(k,v) {
        alert(v.name + ' : ' + v.value);
    });
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: method,
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        //add load indicator
        window.erpui.startload();
        },
      success: function(data) { 
        alert('xhr complete');
        $.each(data, function() {
          alert(this.value + ' data');
          if (this.value == 'error' && this.msg != '') {
              window.erpui.endload();
              window.erpui.notify.error(this.msg); 
              window.erpui.notify.commit();
              } 
          else if (this.value == 'success') {
              window.erpui.endload();
              window.erpui.notify.success(this.msg); 
              window.erpui.notify.commit();                      
              $('.ui-dialog').remove();
              //window.location.href="{% url all_checks %}";  
              //window.location.reload();  
              } 
          });
        },
      error: function() {
          alert('error');
          //remove load indicator   
          window.erpui.endload();   
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You are not unbind delegated event here, your off() line is useless because used before you bind handler

Comment: This seems like either browser caching (yes, some clients--including mobile safari--have been known to cache POST requests!), or something wrong with your `window.erpui.startload()` function.

Comment: could you try, replace off() line with: `var xhr;`  then just before `e.preventDefault();` add this line: `xhr.abort();`  Not sure your server can handle it correctly. BTW, not sure i understand your issue too

Comment: More context: I have a page of links. Each link generates a downloadable report, however some reports require parameters. Selecting a link and getting a report does not require a page reload. So you can select link after link and just keep getting the reports. However, when you select a link that requires parameters and submit it, the data POSTed in that request is used for all other parameter requests.

Comment: At this line 'var data = form.serializeArray();
    $.each(data, function(k,v) {
        alert(v.name + ' : ' + v.value);
    });' on each ajax POST, the result data is the same even though im literally submitting different data.